# Enable or disable form elements in jquery

Tags: jquery

How do I properly disable and enable form elements using jquery. I need to disable the text form element when I click on the select. And vise versa.

```
<html>
    <head>
    <script src="jq.js"></script>
    <script>

    $(function(){

    $('#fromdate').click(function(){
        $('#yosh').attr('disabled','disabled');
        $('#fromdate').removeAttr('disabled');
    });

    $('#yosh').click(function(){
        $('#yosh').removeAttr('disabled');
        $('#fromdate').attr('disabled','disabled');
    });

    });
    </script>

    </head>
    <body>
    Sort by:
    <select name="yosh" id="yosh">
    <option value="daily">daily</option>
    <option value="weekly">yesterday</option>
    <option value="weekly">weekly</option>
    <option value="monthly">monthly</option>
    <option value="yearly">yearly</option>

    </select><br/>
    date range:<br/>

    From:<input type="text" value="" name="fromdate" id="fromdate"></input><br/>
    To:<input type="text" value="" name="todate" id="todate"></input><br/>


    Customer:<input type="text" value="" name="customer" id="customer"></input>

    </body>

    </html>
```

Comment: i think this code should work...are you getting any error with this code?

Comment: The problem with this approach is that you can't click an element once it's disabled. What you can do is wrap the select and text boxes with a span or div and enable/disable the select/text boxes with mouseover event of the span or div.

Comment: You need trigger to do it, add checkbox or button to enable all

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Example of what i've written in the comment:

```
<span id="spnSel">
    <select name="yosh" id="yosh">
        <option value="daily">daily</option>
        <option value="weekly">yesterday</option>
        <option value="weekly">weekly</option>
        <option value="monthly">monthly</option>
        <option value="yearly">yearly</option>
    </select>
</span>
```

Add this event:

```
$('#spnSel').mouseover(function () {
   $('#yosh').prop('disabled', false);
});
```

You can do this for the text boxes as well. This may not be the best solution/approach but it will do the job.

Comment: the ':input' selector comes in handy, to not go too broad within a form... (yes starting with colon, not the general tag, to also catch textarea, etc)

Answer (score 15):

the syntax is

```
$('formelement').attr('disabled',true);
```

or to re-enable

```
$('formelement').removeAttr('disabled');
```

Comment: I think it can't capture the click event once it is disabled, how do I go about that.

Answer (score 2):

look at this...

```
<script>

    $(function(){

    $('#fromdate').click(function(){
        $('#yosh').attr('disabled',true);
        $('#fromdate').removeAttr('disabled');
    });

    $('#yosh').click(function(){
        $('#yosh').removeAttr('disabled');
        $('#fromdate').attr('disabled',true);
    });

    });
    </script>
```

Answer (score 0):

I test your code and i have conclusion that you can't add event while element is disabled, so you have to use trigger...

[***DEMO***](http://jsfiddle.net/jowan/N29vJ/1/)

Answer (score -1):

`$('#fromdate').disabled = false`

Comment: sorry, i used the wrong `attribute` - this is corrected now thank you very much

Comment: That still won't work, you need the native DOM object, just tack `[0]` to the end of your `$()` function to get it.

Comment: .. You event got a comment on fixing your solution so it was viable, and it still hasn't changed? $('#fromdate')[0].disabled = false; ...