# How to disable form options using radio buttons?

Tags: jquery, html

I have two radio buttons on my form. If the user selects one radio option, then some further check box options become unnecessary and therefore I want to disable them. So far the jQuery code I have working disables the options, but if the user then changes their mind and selects the other radio button, the disabled options remain disabled.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    var update = function() {
        if($("#radio_1").prop("checked", true)){
            $('#checkbox_a').prop('disabled', 'disabled');
        } else {
            $('#checkbox_a').prop('disabled', false);
        }
    }
    $(update);
    $("#radio_1").change(update);
</script>
```

HTML:

```
<label for="radio_1"><input type="radio" name="radio" id="radio_1" value="radio_1" />radio_1</label> 
<label for="radio_2"><input type="radio" name="radio" id="radio_2" value="radio_2" />radio_2</label> 
<label for="checkbox_a"><input type="checkbox" name="checkbox[]" id="checkbox_a" value="checkbox_a" />checkbox_a</label>
```

Any ideas?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Enable or disable form elements in jquery](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4965972/enable-or-disable-form-elements-in-jquery)

Comment: This question is specific to radio buttons.

Answer (score 0):

You are not triggering the update when `radio_2` is clicked.

```
var update = function() {
    if($("#radio_1").is(":checked")){
            $('#checkbox_a').prop('disabled', true);
        } else {
            $('#checkbox_a').prop('disabled', false);
        }
}
$(update);
$("input[id^='radio_']").change(update);
```

Notice the `$("input[id^='radio_']").change(update);` to trigger the update when `radio_2` is clicked.

It means whenever an input with an id that [starts with "radio_"](https://api.jquery.com/attribute-starts-with-selector/) is clicked, then do the update.

Answer (score 0):

```
function onOff(obj, target) {
    if ( obj.is(':checked') ) {
        target.prop('disabled', true);
    }
    else {
        target.removeAttr('disabled');
    }
}

$('#radio_1').on('click', function(e) {
    onOff( $(this), $('#checkbox_a') );
});
```

Answer (score -1):

```
 var update = function() {
        if($("#radio_1").is(':checked')){
            $('#checkbox_a').prop('disabled', true);
        } else {
            $('#checkbox_a').prop('disabled', false);
        }
    }
```

Comment: `.prop('disabled', true)` is the right way to disable the element.